# Data Recovery from a corrupted Flash Drive

Tags: recovery

When I plug my flash drive in the USB I get the message that I have to Format the disk in order to use  it. Does that  mean that I have already lost all of my data?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily, you could try data recovery, using free software to recover data is quite common albeit tedious; and without guarantee that even one bit of data isn't corrupted. If that fails, you could try a professional recovery service but those cost quite substantial amounts of money.